# Standalone image manipulation similar to Typo3 GIFBUILDER

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation, typo3

realizing a little project with CodeIgniter I have no access to the most convenient GIFBUILDER of Typo3 as I usually have. The CI image manipulation functions are very basic and I haven't been able to locate anything similar to GIFBUILDER so far.

What I'm looking for is an independent class or even a whole application for image processing beyond cropping and resizing. Target languages would be PHP, Python or Perl. Yet any other language should do as long as the usage of the code is far easier than native methods.

Classes considered so far:

- http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/ (not powerful enough)
- http://code.google.com/p/php-image/wiki/PHPImage (seems to offer much more than phpthumb, yet I'm not full convinced)

Thanks for advice.

cu
Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently stumbled upon WideImage, but haven't tried it yet. It seems to cover most of the GIFBUILDER functions: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Try [imagemaick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). You can use it from commandline or via the php extension for all sorts of image manipulation.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your advice. I was hoping to avoid direct command line execution since its one of the more ugly parts used by GIFBUILDER. Yet it sure is poweful :|